# SQL multiple counts from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following tables `(“All_Countries” & “_Sent”)` and need to get the result as presented in the `“Result”` table. What I want is to count all “SubscriberKeys” and the total `“SendIDs”` connected to these SubscriberKeys, grouped by `“Source”` – just as in the `“Result”` table. I managed to achieve this (I think) by using the query below but I’m not sure if I did it the wrong way. Isn’t there a better (and more efficient) way of doing this with just one select statement and without the extra sub query? I use SQL server 2005.

All_Countries

```
-------------------------------
SubscriberKey*    | Source
-------------------------------
10001             | Campaign1
10002             | Campaign2
10003             | Campaign1
```

_Sent

```
-----------------------
SendID*| SubscriberKey*
-----------------------
1      | 10001
2      | 10001
3      | 10002
4      | 10002
5      | 10003
6      | 10003
```

Result

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Source*          | SubscriberCount       | SendCount
-----------------------------------------------------
Campaign1        | 2                     | 4
Campaign2        | 1                     | 2
```

> Primary keys = * (e.g where you have a star in the column)

```
SELECT a.Source, COUNT(a.SubscriberKey) AS Subscribers, 
(SELECT COUNT(b.SubscriberKey) AS Sent FROM _Sent AS b
INNER JOIN All_Countries AS c ON b.SubscriberKey = c.SubscriberKey
WHERE c.Source = a.Source) AS Sent
FROM All_Countries AS a
GROUP BY a.Source
```

Comment: use `ctrl-K` to format as code, not need insert html to format the spaces.

Comment: Hi @simon-g interesting would be the best I would say ...

Comment: Thanks for the tip @JuanCarlosOropeza! I'm a little bit of a newbie here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  [Source],
        COUNT(DISTINCT a.SubscriberKey) as SubscriberCount,
        COUNT(SendId) as SendCount
FROM All_Countries a
INNER JOIN _Sent s 
    ON s.SubscriberKey = a.SubscriberKey
GROUP BY [Source]
```

Output:

```
Source      SubscriberCount SendCount
Campaign1   2               4
Campaign2   1               2
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this but I think you can get what you want by using the DISTINCT keyword inside your first [COUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175997.aspx)

```
SELECT
    c.Source,
    COUNT(DISTINCT SubscriberKey) AS SubscriberCount,
    COUNT(*) AS SendCount
FROM
    All_Countries c
        JOIN _Sent s ON s.SubscriberKey = c.SubscriberKey 
GROUP BY
    c.Source
```

Answer (score 0):

how about a query like this?

```
select 
    source, count(distinct a.SubscriberKey) as SubscriberCount, count(distinct b.SendID) as SendCount
from All_Countries a join 
     _Sent b ON a.SubscriberKey = b.SubscriberKey
```